# Update 2D numpy array using pairs of indices without iteration

Tags: python, numpy

*Reproducible setup*

I have an array of *n* pairs of indices:

```
indexarray=\
np.array([[0,2,4,6],
          [1,3,5,7]])
```

I also have a 2D array:

```
zeros = np.zeros((10,9))
```

and a list of *n* values:

```
values = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to add each *k*th element from the `values` list to the element in the `zeros` list having indeces equal to the *k*th indices pair

*A solution*

```
# works, but for loop is not suitable for real-world use-case
for index, (row, col) in enumerate(indexarray.T):
    zeros[row, col] = values[index]
```

Visualize what I get:

```
plt.imshow(zeros)
```

[image]

Results as expected.

**How can I do this without iteration?**

---

Similar but different questions:

- [Index 2D numpy array by a 2D array of indices without loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103779/index-2d-numpy-array-by-a-2d-array-of-indices-without-loops) : here the output is an array of pairs of indices, not a 2D array, as here.
- [Fill 2D numpy array from three 1D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118939/fill-2d-numpy-array-from-three-1d-numpy-arrays) : setup is more complicated, they create a 2D array from 1D arrays, unlike here, where we already have a 2D array
- [numpy arrays: filling and extracting data quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559888/numpy-arrays-filling-and-extracting-data-quickly) : way more complicated setup, do not start from 2D array
- [How to convert List of Lists of Tuples- pairs (index,value) into 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936389/how-to-convert-list-of-lists-of-tuples-pairs-index-value-into-2d-numpy-array) : aim is different and for loop is not avoided

Comment: `rows, cols = indexarray[0], indexarray[1]; zeros[rows, cols] = values`?

Comment: Wow, cannot believe I've missed that :) Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to have repeated indices? Do you need to add them together?

Comment: Personally I don't need that, but future users finding this question might; feel free to add an answer covering that case as well if you feel like it - my problem at hand is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use:

```
import numpy as np

indexarray = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 6],
                       [1, 3, 5, 7]])
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

rows, cols = indexarray[0], indexarray[1]

zeros = np.zeros((10, 9))
zeros[rows, cols] = values

print(zeros)
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

An alternative that will add together repeating coordinates, is to use [`add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(zeros, (rows, cols), values)
```

A second alternative is to use a sparse matrix constructor, for example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
rows, cols = indexarray[0], indexarray[1]
zeros = csr_matrix((values, (rows, cols)), shape=(10, 9)).toarray()
```

**Output**

```
[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `indexarray` in indexing.

```
r, c = indexarray
zeros[r, c] = values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
zeros[indexarray[0], indexarray[1]] = values
```